# How to make div top right corner croped

Tags: html, css

I want make `DIV` like below image:

[image]

Please someone help me to achieve this

```css
.div {
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div"></div>
```

Note: div background should be white

Comment: how it is duplicate there is not box shadow to div with white background

Comment: I added 2 duplicates and white is a simple color that you can change easily if in the duplicate you found another color

Comment: @TemaniAfif tried that changing color but no effect

Comment: edit your question to show *your try* and explain how this is not a duplicate.

Comment: @TemaniAfif in my question my div has white background with box shadow

Comment: please take the time to read the duplicates, understand the tricks, then apply them to your case ... If you are waiting for a *ready-to-copy-paste* code then you are in the wrong place. all what you need and even more is detailed in the 10+ answers inside the duplicates

Answer (score 3):

```css
.tag-wrap {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-left:10px solid blue;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(50, 50, 0, 0.3));
}
.tag {
  background: #fff;
  height: 200px;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 90% 0, 100% 30%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="tag-wrap">
  <div class="tag">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have used `clip-path` for this. You can use the below link to generate clip paths!

- https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

FYI `clip path` and `box-shadow` don't work together so you have to follow some rule. Here is the reference link 
https://css-tricks.com/using-box-shadows-and-clip-path-together/

Comment: you're most welcome :)

Comment: at right top should be straight line currently its little bit rounded..can you help me

Comment: Adjust your clip path for small devices

Comment: can we add shadow as per shown image?

Comment: with white background not gray

Comment: done, adjust bgcolor as u want

Comment: need box shadow too

Comment: already given check, maybe u can't see because the color is too light

Comment: Check i have made it more visible @VikasJadhav

Answer (score 3):

This is the best result i could get working

```css
.parent {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-left:10px solid blue
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 20px 20px 0;
  border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how to add shadow as per attached image?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.cpath{
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    clip-path: polygon(70% 0,100% 50%,100% 100%,0% 100%,0% 0%);
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px;
    border-left: 4px solid purple;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;

}
```

```html
<div class="cpath">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This CSS

```css
.div {
      height: 200px;
      background: blue;
      border-radius: 4px;
      border-top-right-radius: 40px;
    }
    
        .div::before {
                content: '';
                position: absolute;
                top: 8px;
                right: 8px;
                border-top: 58px solid white;
                border-left: 40px solid #0012ff;
                width: 0;
            }
```

```html
<div class="div"></div>
```